# Knnclassify() matlab

Tags: cross-validation, matlab

I am currently working on matlab and I am new to it. I would like to know how do i average the results from the folds (or otherwise combined) to produce a single estimation.

My dataset has 2 class labels +1 and -1. and k=5. I use the knnclassify() method in matlab in order to perform cross validation.

Kindly help!

Comment: Can you please make your question a bit more understandable? It seems as you want to use Cross-Validation to make classification itself, but this is nonsense.

Answer (score 6):

The knnclassify() function uses the k-nearest neighbours classification algorithm to perform classification. The crossvalind() function is a separate one to divide a data set in to folds to perform cross-validation. Both are part of the Bioinformatics toolbox. I suggest that you read the documentation associated with them, so that you can be sure you are using them correctly.

In general, however, with a single n-fold cross-validation (CV) run, you don't really need to average results from folds. You just collect the results from the individual folds.

For example, with 5-fold CV, your dataset is divided into 5 separate folds, used as follows:

- Train with Folds 1..4, Test on Fold 5
- Train with Folds 1..3+5, Test on Fold 4
- Train with Folds 1+2+4+5 Test on Fold 3
  and so on.

So all of the data is used for testing exactly once. You can just combine the test results in a single list, and count how many it got right and wrong to compute the overall accuracy.

Answer (score 2):

```
load fisheriris
indices = crossvalind('Kfold',species,10);
cp = classperf(species); % initializes the CP object
for i = 1:10
    test = (indices == i); train = ~test;
    class = knnclassify(meas(test,:),meas(train,:),species(train));
    % updates the CP object with the current classification results
    classperf(cp,class,test);  
end
cp.CorrectRate % queries for the correct classification rate
```

Comment: +1 but (1) You can format your code using indentation (with 4 spaces or through the online editor); (2) Some comments around your code might be appreciated because users that are not familiar with Matlab syntax will have hard time to understand what the above code chunk actually does. As far as I understand, predicted class memberships on the test sample are stored at each iteration, and then averaged to yield the classification CR.